# Schengen visa for round trip can my arrival and departure destination be different?

Tags: schengen-visas

I am an Indian citizen studying in Belarus. I am planning to travel to European countries this summer. Can my arrival and departure destination be different. I will be traveling from Minsk Belarus to European countries but going to India from there. Can it be possible?

Answer (score 2):

## Yes.

In your visa application you will describe your planned itinerary. If you list your arrival, departure, and all statesin between, there is no problem at all with a round trips. (There are rules to determine which embassy would handle your application.)

Even if you mentioned only one destination country in your application, you can arrive and depart through other Schengen states. But for a first trip it is a good idea to spell it out in the application and to stick to the plan.